# AWS Lambda HTTP accessible from the internet, but not accessible from an EC2 on the same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda function, that has an API Gateway attached to it. It has a publicly accessible IP address and a domain name (Created by the serverless framework). I can access it from the broad internet, from my own browser (and other devices).

The issue is, it seems to be inaccessible from other services on my account, like an EC2 instance. From the mentioned instance, `curl google.com` works and returns a response, but curl `mylink.com` times out.

I think this has something to do with VPC setup, but I can't put my finger at it. What might be the issue here?

Update: Using `curl --verbose`, I found out that while accessed from anywhere else, the IP the API Gateway is leading to is different, than when accessed from within my AWS account. The VPC doesn't seem to matter, I created a new VPC, an EC2 instance inside it, and it still did the same.

Comment: Do you have VPC interface endpoint for api gateway?

Comment: Can you show your route table for that VPC?

Comment: SO doesn't allow links, so I'll describe:
172.31.0.0/16 local active, 0.0.0.0/0 igw-69***** active

Comment: Did you do any modification to a default VPC?

Comment: None that I know of.

Comment: By the way, if you respond to comments. its better to tag @Marcin. Otherwise, no notifications are obtained.

Comment: So why do you think that it has "something to do with VPC setup" if your default VPC is not modified? Also what about the  VPC interface endpoint for api gateway? Have you created any in the VPC?

Comment: @Marcin I think so, because I can't see any other way this could be an issue, short of on-spot software level configuration, which I definitely have not changed (and tried creating defaults). About the API endpoints, the Serverless framework handles that for me, so I haven't modified it at all. I went into the Virtual Private Gateways tab, and there indeed are not any.

Comment: Can you also share a screenshot of your security group, as those are the usual suspect for connection timeout error?

Comment: `Virtual Private Gateways tab` is the wrong one. Please check in the `Endpoints` tab if you have any endpoints created for the VPC in question.

Comment: @StefanN imgur. com /qKXKUdp , outbound rules are set to allow all outbound traffic.

Comment: @Marcin Yeah, there is an entry in the Endpoints tab.

Comment: Entry for what? API gateway?

Comment: @Marcin "Endpoint type: Interface"

Comment: But what is it for? S3, api gateway, dynamo db, ...?

Comment: @Marcin How do I look that up?

Comment: It will be given in the same place where `Endpoint type: Interface` is

Comment: @Marcin `com.amazonaws.us-east-2.execute-api` it says under Service Name. Is that it?

Comment: Can you remove it?

Comment: @Marcin So, that worked. Could you, please, create an answer explaining how and why that works, and I'll award you the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by the presence of [VPC interface endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/endpoint-services-overview.html) for API Gateway in the default VPC. The VPC interface endpoint for API gateway is used for [private API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html), not public APIs as used be the OP. Subsequently, **calls to public API endpoints fail**, as explained in [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/):

> When they’re configured as private, the **public networks are not made available** to route your API. Instead, your API can only be accessed using the interface endpoints that you have configured.

There are two ways to combat the issue:

- disable  [Private DNS Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/verify-domains.html) option for the endpoint, or
- remove the endpoint.

In the OP's case, the second option was used to **solve** the problem.

Comment: How come the OP was able to access the Lambda function through the API Gateway from the Internet then? BTW thanks for a nice explanation.

Comment: @StefanN Thanks.The question was opposite.  How to access public API gateway from lambda in VPC.

Comment: OK. But in the initial description of the question (first paragraph), the OP states that he can access the Lambda function from the internet. Why is that the case if "public networks are not made available"?

Comment: @StefanN The lambda was fronted with a public API. There was no access to the API from an ec2 instance. This can happen  due to api gateway interface endpoint which can shadow the public dns names of an api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The EC2 instance likely lives inside a VPC which doesn't have public internet access (or may but through a load balancer, bastion host, or any myriad of other options).

You'll need to find out which VPC the EC2 instance lives in, and ensure your lambda function has access to it. You can add a function to a VPC by following [the documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/)

Comment: It's inside the default VPC, and it does have internet access. Just not access to that particular lambda, oddly enough.

More interestingly, it did have access to it just a few days ago. Not it just stopped working, along with another EC2 machine in the same VPC.